# Can you recommend a good image manipulation dll for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, image, image-manipulation

Looking for a library that will allow me to size and resize images using c# and ASP.net on a Windows 2003 Server.

Comment: WIC isn't supported for use in ASP.NET. Although GDI isn't either, [it works as long as you avoid these pitfalls, and it doesn't require Full Trust like WIC](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/). WIC is probably subject to most of the same pitfalls listed in the article, so be careful.  And if you would rather take a tried and true route, just [use the ImageResizing.Net](http://imageresizing.net) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the built-in classes in the `System.Drawing` namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx

Note, as was pointed out in the comment below, the [Windows Imaging Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be a better fit.

Here is a tutorial: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing

Comment: `System.Drawing` is not always recommended for us with ASP.NET: _'Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components.'_ [System.Drawing on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx).

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like that is referring to Windows services and web services? I'll add a link to the Windows Imaging Components.

Comment: Check my latest addition and Mr. Disappointment's comment - you may want to look into the Windows Imaging Components. I've used the System.Drawing namespace in an ASP.Net application before with no issues so I'm not sure what the warning really means.

Comment: How about this then? have you used this? http://www.brothersoft.com/windows-imaging-component-78469.html

Comment: I never noticed that bit until now. I'm guessing that they did that because so many people were writing such terrible code and not realizing that they need to clean up after themselves. People don't realize that a web app isn't just the lifetime of a single user. Anyway, I've been using `System.Drawing` on several very high traffic websites with zero problems.

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author.

The free [ImageResizing.Net](http://imageresizing.net) library is precisely what you're looking for.

It's stable, mature (since 2007), actively developed, supported, and... open source.

It is specifically designed to provide image manipulation for ASP.NET, while avoiding all of the GDI bugs. It provides a highly-scalable and efficient manipulation API that often only requires 1 line of code to use. It doesn't leak memory or handles, and has 0 known bugs as of this writing.

If you decide to [roll your own solution, PLEASE read this list of pitfalls to avoid](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/). And for those thinking WIC is the solution - it is unsupported for use from ASP.NET.

Site link:
[ASP.NET Image Resizing Module for IIS](http://imageresizing.net)

Answer (score 2):

Another free (Microsoft blessed) alternative is `System.Web.Helpers.WebImage`. `WebImage` is part of the [**ASP.NET Web Pages**](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15979) library.

After installation, the assemblies are located in:

> ```
> Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies
> ```

#### Example

```
public void GetResized()
{
    new WebImage(ImagePath)
        .Resize(200, 200) // resize image to 200x200 px
        .Write();
}
```

Other example usages [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/15/asp-net-mvc-3-beta-simple-image-manipulations-using-webimage-helper.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [**Atalasoft Photo (Free) DotImage SDK**](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/feature-matrix) for basic image manipulation:

http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/feature-matrix

Works well for my needs and including thumbnail processing & cropping and has tons of image format support which also comes free with the SDK.

Comment: +1 Very nice I will give it a try, thank you for the link. This actually looks much easier to implement than the previous answer, as this seems to have a lot more options built in than WIC. I will comment and let you know what I think when I implement.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Just be sure to put a little study on the SDK docs especially in the `Atalasoft.Imaging.ImageProcessing` namespace where most of the image commands are. I use `Thumbnail` quite alot. There's also `ResampleCommand` and `CropCommand`. Usually, you begin manipulation with `using(var i = new AtalaImage( data ))`, then `AnyCommand.Apply[To]( i )` which returns a `new AtalaImage` with the applied command, from which you can save your altered image.

Comment: Also, be mindful to use the correct x86 or x64 binary to use in your application.